# How to start in full screen in Monogame?

Tags: c#, wpf, monogame

I'm developing a game using Monogame and C#. I have a wpf application for the menu that starts in full screen. When I click on play on the menu, I go to the Monogame project. How can I start the Monogame solution in full screen like I do with the wpf menu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `IsFullscreen` property to `true`.

```
//you likely already have this line (or similar)
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

//set the GraphicsDeviceManager's fullscreen property
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
```

Comment: keyboardP is correct.  If this doesn't work go enter a bug report on the [MonoGame issues page](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues).

Comment: toggling works by setting the isFullScreen flag and then graphics.ApplyChanges();

Comment: Monogame apparently has a known issue in which full screen mode does not work yet.  Setting IsFullScreen works in XNA, but is immediately set back to false in Monogame.  The known work-around seems to be using a borderless, fullscreen window, which I am still trying to get working myself.  I'm told this depends on which version of Windows is being used.

Answer (score 4):

This is the right way with monogame

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
graphics.ToggleFullScreen();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make the application fullscreen. One is by setting the `IsFullScreen` property, the other is by calling the `ToggleFullScreen` Method.

Keep in mind that, according to the [documentation](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.html#Microsoft_Xna_Framework_GraphicsDeviceManager_IsFullScreen), if you change the property during initialization this will automatically set fullscreen mode. But when changing the property, not in initialization, that you need to call the `ApplyChanges` method.

```cs
// probably already defined
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

// ...

graphics.IsFullScreen = true;

// don't forget to call ApplyChanges, if you are not in the Initialize method
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

```cs
// probably already defined 
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

// ...

graphics.ToggleFullScreen();
```